# Reuse Module to add controller?

Tags: angularjs

I try to add a controller to an existing module. But I always get the following error message:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pmm' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

**app.js**

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pmm', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap', ...
  ])
})();
```

**login.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('pmm')
        .controller('LoginCtrl',LoginCtrl);
    function LoginCtrl() {

    }
})();
```

Comment: Make sure app.js is injected in your index.html before login.js

Comment: @Gustav - sorry I didn't see your comment when I wrote the same answer. You answer first - so if our guess is correct, then *your* should be marked as answer :)

Comment: Thank you! They was'nt in the correct order. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show HTML file? You probably didn't include app.js in it...